# How to Associate Case-Related Emails with Cases in SugarCRM

Tags: sugarcrm, suitecrm

Cases Related emails are not listed in History sub-panel of the case’s.

I have 2 inbound email groups: Sales and Support. When a rep replies to an email from one of the group folders, I want the Sales rep to respond from the Sales Email account and the Support rep to respond from the Support Email account. I have created security groups for Sales and Support but I can't see how to apply the security group to each Email Group. Perhaps this feature is not available yet?

Comment: What did you try already?

Comment: http://support.sugarcrm.com/Knowledge_Base/Email/Automatically_Associating_Emails_With_Cases/index.html